# Exponential laws in modular arithmetic | disappearing mod N

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Why is $(g^b \bmod N)^a \bmod N = g^{a*b} \bmod N$ ?

Specifically: Why/how does the mod N in the round brackets disappear from the first expression $(g^b \bmod N)^a \bmod N$?

I know of the exponential law that $g(^a)^b$ is equal to $g^{a*b}$ but I just do not understand why the $\bmod n$ in the round braces just disappears. Can someone help me with that? Has this anything to do with the exponential law or something entirely different?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by $x \bmod N$, you mean the remainder when $x$ is divided by $N$. (Otherwise, the expression "$(g^b \bmod N)^a \bmod N$" is hard to interpret. Is the mod of a power of a mod a number? A residue class?)

The integer $g^b \bmod N$ differs from $g^b$ by some multiple of $N$. That is,
$$g^b \bmod N = g^b + jN$$
for some integer $j$. For the same reason, $(g^b \bmod N)^a \bmod N$ differs from $(g^b \bmod N)^a$ by a multiple of $N$:
$$(g^b \bmod N)^a \bmod N = (g^b \bmod N)^a + kN$$
for some integer $k$.

Putting these two equations together,
$$(g^b \bmod N)^a \bmod N = (g^b + jN)^a + kN$$
If you expand $(g^b + jN)^a$, you get $(g^b)^a$ plus a lot of other terms that are all multiples of $N$, so
$$(g^b \bmod N)^a \bmod N = (g^b)^a + mN$$
for some $m$. Therefore
$$(g^b \bmod N)^a \bmod N = (g^b)^a \bmod N\,.$$